# Use a DockerFile to create an empty MSSQL Express database in a container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am a little confused as to how all of this works as this is my first time playing with Docker.

I've downloaded the following docker image of Microsoft SQL Server Express (https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/mssql-server-windows-express/).

I am trying to docker-compose together some existing containers and every time I run `docker-compose up`, what I want to have happen is that a new database is created and a target container is run.

Here is the existing Dockerfile for the container that I want to have execute. "Execute this" is the container that I want to have `dotnet run` run on and any "HelperService" are services that should be up before the target container is run:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.0-runtime-nanoserver-1709 AS base
WORKDIR /app

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.0-sdk-nanoserver-1709 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ExecuteThis/ExecuteThis.csproj ExecuteThis/
COPY ../HelperService/HelperService.csproj ../HelperService/
COPY ../HelperService2/HelperService2.csproj ../HelperService2/
COPY ../HelperService3/HelperService3.csproj ../HelperService3/
COPY ../HelperService4/HelperService4.csproj ../HelperService4/
COPY ../HelperService5/HelperService5.csproj ../HelperService5/
COPY ../HelperService6/HelperService6.csproj ../HelperService6/
RUN dotnet restore ExecuteThis/ExecuteThis.csproj
COPY . .
WORKDIR /src/ExecuteThis
RUN dotnet build ExecuteThis.csproj -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish ExecutThis.csproj -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "ExecuteThis.dll"]
```

Here is a `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  sqlserver:
    image: microsoft/mssql-server-windows-express
  helperservice:
    image: helperservice
  helperservice2:
    image: helperservice2
  helperservice3:
    image: helperservice3
  helperservice4:
    image: helperservice4
  helperservice5:
    image: helperservice5
  helperservice6:
    image: helperservice6
  executethis:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY}executethis
    depends_on:
      - sqlserver
      - helperservice
      - helperservice2
      - helperservice3
      - helperservice4
      - helperservice5
      - helperservice6
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ExecuteThis\Dockerfile
```

My question is: how do I generate a database and where should I write those instructions? How do I `dotnet run` my "ExecuteThis" container?

Comment: I hope you get an answer soon.  I want to ask pretty much the same question as I have been round in circles for a few days now.  I've currently got a `docker-compose.yml` with 2 services - each of which uses a separate `dockerfile`.  I get an aspnet core container up and running but I am struggling to get any form of sql server database using `sqlcmd`

Comment: Check this link if you want to attach an empty database - http://ericsmasal.com/2018/06/22/sql-server-2016-on-docker-for-development/.  Not sure what you are wanting to do for your scenario?

Comment: Posted my specific question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52105555/create-sql-server-database-from-a-script-in-docker