# Create SQL Server database from a script in docker

Tags: sql-server, docker, docker-compose, containers, dockerfile

Simple question I hope. I cannot find anything anywhere.

How do you create a database in a `Microsoft SQL Server` `Docker` container?

**Dockerfile**:

I am looking at the following `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM microsoft/mssql-server-windows-developer:latest

ENV sa_password ab873jouehxaAGR

WORKDIR /
COPY /db-scripts/create-db.sql .

# here be the existing run commnd in the image microsoft/mssql-server-windows-developer:latest
#CMD ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';", ".\\start -sa_password $env:sa_password -ACCEPT_EULA $env:ACCEPT_EULA -attach_dbs \\\"$env:attach_dbs\\\" -Verbose" ]

RUN (sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA -P ab873jouehxaAGR -i create-db.sql)
```

**docker-compose.yml**:

I have put together the following docker compose file:

```
version: '3.4'

services: 
  sql.data:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY}myfirst-mssql:latest
    container_name: myfirst-mssql_container
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    environment:
      SA_PASSWORD: ab873jouehxaAGR
      ACCEPT_EULA: Y
```

**Bringing it together**

I am running the command `docker-compose up` against the above.  And assuming `create-db.sql` file will simply create a database which is not relevant here to keep things minimal.

**Errors**

The error I get above is that the login for SA is invalid when it runs the `.sql` script:

```
Step 7/7 : RUN (sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA -P ab873jouehxaAGR -i create-db.sql)
 ---> Running in 2ac5644d0bd9
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server : Login failed for user 'SA'..
```

It looks like this runs before the password has been changed to ab873jouehxaAGR which typically looks like the command from `mssql-server-windows-developer:latest.json` from inspecting the image in vscode - `\start -sa_password $env:sa_password -ACCEPT_EULA $env:ACCEPT_EULA -attach_dbs` actually does.

**Environment**

I am running docker `Docker version 18.06.1-ce, build e68fc7a` on Windows 10.

**Attach or script**

I am not specifying attaching a database using the environment variable `attach_dbs` of which I see in many examples.

I am trying to find a best practice for managing a sql container from a point of view of end to end testing and a lot of articles seem to not cover the data aspect part - ie [Development Workflow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/microservices-architecture/docker-application-development-process/docker-app-development-workflow)

I would be interested to hear in comments thoughts on these two approaches in the Docker world.

Comment: I've been struggling with a similar issue - during setup you're meant to set other environment variables too, but it seems to ignore them for me.  Also, worth noting is that the base Microsoft docker container for SQL Server doesn't have Full Text Search enabled in it. (edit, my experience with docker scripting on windows hasn't been completely smooth, it's hard work for even simple things, it's like negotiating brexit)

Answer (score 0):

using following commands can solve your problem

```
docker-compose up --build -d

version: '3.4'
services: 
  sql.data:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY}myfirst-mssql:latest
    container_name: myfirst-mssql_container
    environment:
      SA_PASSWORD: ab873jouehxaAGR
      ACCEPT_EULA: Y
```

and after that:

```
docker exec myfirst-mssql_container sqlcmd 
  -d master 
  -S localhost
  -U "sa"
  -P "ab873jouehxaAGR"
  -Q 'select 1'
```

Comment: speaking to another using #Andrez is only allow in comment but not in answer. Whz ? Because, the order of answers can change and your answer will not always follow #Andrez question ! I will change change your answer myself.